# Google Play Services 9.2.0 causes undesired crash in device without Google Play Services - NPE at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity

Tags: android

Previously, I using the following Google Play Services 8.4.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
```

When I run the app in device without Google Play Services installed. Here's the dialog I'm getting. No crash after I press the dialog button.

[image]

However, after I migrate to Google Play Services 9.2.0 with Firebase

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
```

I get a different dialog box.

[image]

The app crashes after I press the dialog button

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1409)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$1.zzasn(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.onClick(Unknown Source)
     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea on how I can avoid such crash?

Comment: I held the update to 9.2.0 waiting for a fix, now that 9.2.1 is out I'm disappointed that this is not already fixed. Downgrading to 9.0.2 is my current workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occure when if you have emulator or device in which `google play services` are not installed. To work around to save app for crashing. use following step

> 1. Override startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode)
> 2. In startActivityForResult add super call
>      super.startActivityForResult in try catch and catch the
>      NullPointerException
>
> Easy its done Now you can trap the nullpointerexception here and add
>   your error handling in catch

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    try {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // fixes here..
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to consider case there are devices in the market which doesn't have GPS.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng for that I can give purposal to hand it on `catch` block.